# Laravel - Model Method from Child Controller

Tags: php, laravel, model, controllers

I have a base controller which injects a User model in it's constructor:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
        View::share('user', $this->user);
    }
```

AuthController extends the BaseController

```
class AuthController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(LDAP $ldap, User $user) {
        parent::__construct($user);
        $this->ldap = $ldap;
        $this->user->setUsername('Username'); //This is not being called
    }
```

How can I access the injected model from the parent controller and call methods on it?

If I use $this->user->setUsername('Username'); from the BaseController the method is called correctly, but not from the child controller.

Comment: this would normally work. Have you tried vardumping the user variable?  try `var_dump($this->user);` before you call `setUsername()` in AuthController and see what you get.

Comment: My code is working as it should. Turns out the variable was being set correctly, but then cleared after login...